# VirtualBox does not show 64-bit options

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm having trouble with VirtualBox on Ubuntu. I want to create a 64-bit virtual machine, but VB only gives me 32-bit options (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCKlR.png)). I installed VirtualBox on macOS, and it works fine. However, when I installed VB on Ubuntu I got this problem.

How can I get the 64-bits options with VB? How can I enable hardware virtualization?

In fact, I wanted to install `gnome-software` on Ubuntu in following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqAXRqqUnpE), but it is not possible because of this problem.

I have a Macbook Pro (Mid-2012, 13-inch), and Ubuntu 64-bit with Parallels

Comment: Check that virtualization are enabled in the BIOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable hardware virtualization with a Macbook Pro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/838030/enable-hardware-virtualization-with-a-macbook-pro)

Comment: Whoops, the other question is a duplicate of this one because it was posted after. I voted too soon. Also the other question is probably off-topic...

Comment: @wjandrea: Doesn't matter IMO. It's almost the same question anyway, and the OP shouldn't have posted it twice.

Answer (score 1):

That is because Vt/x is disabled , you can enable in BIOS look for it in there

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know how to enable hardware virtualization (in there?). Could you help me at this point?

Comment: when your computer is booting up enter the BIOS usually (F2) {can be different} then go to advance options then in there u should see an option like "Intel (R) Virtualization Technology" then enable it, then go to Exit option choose save changes then exit

Comment: This is true with Windows, but I don't think it is true with OS X. Are you sure of that?

Comment: It makes no difference because BIOS is on the motherboard, if u are struggling to find your BIOS key, search on Google (YourPCName) BIOS key

Comment: but in Mac it is UEFI so just search how to enable VT/x in UEFI Mac

Comment: Yes in bios I enabled both Virtual Vt/x and Virtual Environment in intel and it worked for me ..Thanks Stack Exchange